# Subset Dataset in r based on three columns

Tags: r

In the following data frame for those records where id and name are same I want to remove those rows where class is 0

[image]

for e.g. 1st and 2nd record have same id and name. Similarly 3rd and 4th record.

The final data frame will be as below

[image]

Please help how to do it in r. My actual dataset has thousands of such records

Here is the sample dataset

```
Data <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5),name = c("asd","asd","pqr","pqr","fgh","yut","kju"),
           date = c("02/03/2022","10/05/2022","23/01/2022","15/04/2022","19/05/2022","14/02/2022","10/06/2022"),
           class = c(0,1,0,1,0,0,1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try,

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(!(n() > 1 &  class == 0))

     id name  date       class
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
1     1 asd   10/05/2022     1
2     2 pqr   15/04/2022     1
3     3 fgh   19/05/2022     0
4     4 yut   14/02/2022     0
5     5 kju   10/06/2022     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Or an `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(Data)
unique(Data[order(id, -class)], by="name")
```

**Output:**

```
| id|name |date       | class|
|--:|:----|:----------|-----:|
|  1|asd  |10/05/2022 |     1|
|  2|pqr  |15/04/2022 |     1|
|  3|fgh  |19/05/2022 |     0|
|  4|yut  |14/02/2022 |     0|
|  5|kju  |10/06/2022 |     1|
```